# If you have developed an app for mobile devices, which line did you take?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, windows-phone-7, webkit

Developing mobile apps is a challenging job.

Customers want to be present not only on iPhone and iPad but maybe on Android and other **mobile platforms** like Windows Phone 7, Blackberry and Symbian, too.

It costs a lot of money to keep this apps up to date on **different platforms**. Besides the developer has to dig in different sdk's and learn different languages.

I thought about having just **one app**, that is rendered in a mobile browser like webkit, which is a standart for rendering web content.

Of course there are constraints like the use of camera or specific hardware for advanced rendering. But I think this will change over time.

**How do you challange that? Do you re-use your code? Could mobile web be an alternative?**

Comment: @ArtRorkAD Not an answer to your question but you may be interested in http://www.phonegap.com/

Comment: Better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to make the same app for multiple platforms (iPhone, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone 7, etc.), I'd probably create a web app and utilize the new HTML5 features.

Alternatively, if you want to use the native languages (for added support with camera, etc.), it'd be quite hard to reuse the code. You could use the same logic, but you'd still have to rewrite a lot of the actual code.

Some other options could be [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) or [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Using a web app bundler like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile web can surely be an alternative.

I have been hearing a lot of things HTML5 is promising for mobile devices. If all of that becomes a reality, then we can really create web apps as powerful as native apps!

Answer (score 1):

If your app is fairly simple and doesn't require the camera, fancy graphics or location based services then a HTML5 app is the way to go. Otherwise what I would do is develop it on the platform that you are most comfortable with and then outsource development to people who are specialised in the other platform(s). It's hard enough keeping up with one platform let alone five.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is unfortunately not going to solve this problem for you because the companies have no vested interest in working together. We have tried middle layer products but you always come up against a roadblock that they cannot overcome or a device they do not support (e.g. our latest app is for BlackBerry PlayBook which uses Adobe AIR and a PlayBook SDK which is in constant flux).

My recommendation would be develop you apps using an early version of Java and implement this separately for each platform.

Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't agree with this at all. What do you mean "the companies have no vested interest in working together"? This is a very misleading answer...

Comment: IF a feature comes with HTML5, and manufacturers want to ship their devices with HTML5 compliant web browsers, then they'll have all the features that HTML5 defines. I think this is quite possible in the near future. In a conference, I heard someone saying that at a later point of time they can also include support of device camera and other things in HTML5. So you see, possibilities have no end this way.

Comment: Yeah, well a web application should display the same on all devices, unless their browser doesn't comply to the normal standards. Most of them are using webkit though, which means that it should comply. It makes no difference if the companies are competing - the fact is that they should be complying to the web standards when displaying web apps, end of story.

Comment: Sorry my answer about HTML5 was not very in depth (it had been done to death by other people and is common knowledge). HTML5 is not going to be a magic bullet because it takes a long time to agree standards. Manufacturers are not going to wait months or years for HTML5 to catch up with their new inventions. They are more likely to provide API access to these new functions through their own SDKs (hence building apps in Java so these can be utilised). I have had discussions with development managers from the leading mobile OSes and HTML5 is not one of their priorities.

Comment: It doesn't have to be their main priority, they could just use Webkit, which is developed by another company. So let webkit worry about the standards, and they can get on with other things.

Comment: Further to my additional explanation about why I would not rely on device manufacturers implementing HTML5 anytime soon it has just been announced that the finalised spec for HTML5 will not appear until at least 2014.